# Is this a proper use of "this is not to say"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Is this a proper use of the phrase, "this is not to say," relative to the meaning of the sentence that precedes it?

> Your memoir is interesting, eye-opening, and most importantly, clear.
>   This is not to say that I had no questions while reading, however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is clear, idiomatic and grammatically correct English.

Personally I would have used, "**that** is not to say" but it's a matter of preference and style.

Comment: Yes, me too. I would have used *that*.

Comment: Perhaps a sentence indicating why it's idiomatic would be helpful.